# Change value value of field using AMPscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

In my Data Extension there is a field,  `Age`, with a value of `100`.

I want to change this value from `100` to something completely different like `Red` or `One-Hundred`.

Can this be done with AMPscript?

Note: **the Field has the number Data Type.**

**Update:**

My current solution is replacing my `Age` field, however the code after the ELSEIF is not being executed. I'm not sure why.

```
%%[ 
    
    var @Age 
    
    IF @Age > "99" THEN 
    set @termsYear = "Whole of life" 
    UpdateDE("TestDE",1,"Age", @Age, "Age", @termsYear) 
    ELSEIF @Age < "99" THEN 
    set @termsYear = AttributeValue("Age") 
    ENDIF 

]%%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it’s a number, then you can only change it to another number, and you can do it using the Update functions I mention below.

If you need a text field, the I suggest you add a brand new column to your DE with a text field type.

Then, use the Update function to change/add new values:

[UpdateDE](https://ampscript.guide/updatede/) (used in email):

> This function updates the Data Extension row referenced in the column
> and value arguments. Values updated are specified with column name and
> value pairs. This function does not return a value.

[UpdateData](https://ampscript.guide/updatedata/) (used on a CloudPage):

> This function updates the Data Extension row referenced in the column
> and value arguments. Values updated are specified with column name and
> value pairs. It returns the number of rows updated by the operation.

Comment: UpdateDE is working for the most part. I have updated my question with some additional code. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Two comments on the script you added: you should identify a row to update by it’s primary key, not by age, and like mentioned above, you cannot update a numeric field with text

Comment: Apologies I missed the part, identifying a new row. Thank you for your answer, Zuzanna.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot update the value in a **number** type field by a **text** value, like @zuzannamj suggested above, you should create a new column field with the text field type.

For example: If I have the new text field type call "Age in text", I would try like something like this:

```AMPscript
%%[ 
    var @Age
    set @Age = AttributeValue("Age") 
    set @Age = 100 /* test */
    
    IF @Age >= 99 THEN 
    set @termsYear = "Whole of life" 
    UpdateDE("TestDE",1,"Age", @Age, "Age in text", @termsYear)
    ELSEIF @Age < 99 THEN 
    set @termsYear = @Age
    ENDIF 

]%%
Output: %%=v(@termsYear)=%%
```

Comment: Right ok, all makes sense now. I need to create a new column. Thanks